# $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times k}$ with orthonormal columns in $\mathbb R^n$ where $k<n$. Prove that $rank(I_n-AA^T)=n-k$

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem with this is that I believe $AA^T=I$ since it has orthonormal vectors. But if that's the case then wouldn't the $rank(I_n-AA^T)=0$ since this would be a $0$ matrix? But this seems like a trivial case.

Comment: Omit the last column in a $3\times3$ identity matrix and call the resulting $3\times2$ matrix $A$.  This matrix has orthogonal columns. Check the statement for this.

Comment: If the matrix has orthonormal columns then $A^TA=I$, but $AA^T$ will not be $I$ if $k<n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$\operatorname{rank}(I_n-AA^T)+\dim\ker(I_n-AA^T)=n,$$
it is enough to prove that $\ker(I_n-AA^T)$ has dimension $k$. This is a consequence of the fact that $\ker(I_n-AA^T)$ is actually the image of $A$, which has dimension $k$ since the columns of $A$ must be linearly independent.

To prove that $\ker(I_n-AA^T)=\operatorname{im}(A)$, we use the fact that $A^TA=I$ (because the columns of $A$ are orthonormal). This gives us
$$(I_n-AA^T)Av=Av-AA^TAv=Av-Av=0$$
for all $v\in \mathbb{R}^k$, and thus $\operatorname{im}(A)\subset \ker(I_n-AA^T)$. For the other inclusion, consider $w\in \ker(I_n-AA^T)$; then $w=AA^Tw\in \operatorname{im}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $U = I - AA^T$ is idempotent. So $\operatorname{rank}(U) = \operatorname{trace}(U).$

$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{trace}(U) &=  \operatorname{trace}(I_n) - \operatorname{trace}(AA^T)\\ & = n - \operatorname{trace}(A^TA)  \\ &= n - \operatorname{trace}(I_k) = n - k.
\end{align*}$